# How to manually place data in a boost::asio::streambuf to later read it with a std::istream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to use a std::istream as data source. I want to *place* custom binary data in the istream's stream buffer so it can later be retrieved from the istream.

I have read about boost::asio::streambuf and how it is used to do exactly what I want but using a socket as data source instead of an in-memory buffer, which is what I would like to use.

From what I understand from the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html), the steps should be:

1. Create a boost::asio::streambuf
2. Create a std::istream passing the streambuf
3. Invoke boost::asio::streambuf::prepare to get the list of buffers representing the output sequence.
4. Somehow write in the output sequence.
5. Invoke boost::asio::streambuf::commit to move what I wrote in the output sequence to the input sequence.
6. Read from the std::istream from step 2 normally with std::stream::read.

I don't know how to address step 4, so I don't know even if I'm going in the right direction.

Are the depicted steps correct? If so, how to address step 4?

Comment: Relevant: [Is it possible to "prepare" input from cin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013638/is-it-possible-to-prepare-input-from-cin).

Comment: @Xeo that's exactly what I want to do but with binary data instead of text. As I understand with stringstream it would not be possible. Am I right? Is there any other stream implementation that could be used for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily send any std stream, so you can also you a `stringstream`. You can write binary data to your stringstream (it is just a byte array, effectively).

A few samples:

```
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream.write(&binarydata_buf, sizeof(binarydata_buf));
// or use stream operators: request_stream << "xxx" << yyy;

// Send the request.
boost::asio::write(socket, request);
```

If you already have a fully populated istream (using std::cin as dummy in this example):

```
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream << std::cin.rdbuf() << std::flush;

// Send the request.
boost::asio::write(socket, request);
```

Ways to populate an istream are e.g. `ostream::write` or [Boost Serialization `binary_archive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)

There are many ways to skin a cat of course, so be sure to think over the other options before blindly copying this.

See [How to send ostream via boost sockets in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675358/how-to-send-ostream-via-boost-sockets-in-c/5675952#5675952)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just transmit the data across a socket into your streambuf? If you can link the std::istream to the asio::streambuf which is listening on a particular socket, just use the same socket with boost::asio::write to send it data.

There isn't much penalty to using actual sockets intra-process, rather than trying to simulated it by accessing underlying data structures.

Comment: wut? that seems like funny advice to me

Comment: I agree the approach you propose is feasible, but it seems a bit overkill to me. My final purpose with this, is to unit test a piece of code that is stream-oriented, and I would prefer not to involve extra software elements unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Youre already pulling in boost::asio, so it seemed to fit in with your proposed framework. why not just use a std::iostream constructed with any streambuf? It casts to istream just fine

Comment: Unit tests are meant to test a small software component (e.g. class, function) in isolation. To me, using a network connection as part of a test breaks such _isolation_.