# How to send ostream by socket in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, ostream

I am trying to send `ostream` which contains binary data by socket in C++.

I'm using [Microsoft SEAL](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL) for 
developing about encryption. 
Now I need to send a **ciphertext** from client to server. Microsoft SEAL provides a function
 `void Ciphertext::save(ostream &stream) const` 
to serialize the **Ciphertext** object to `ostream`, but after calling 
`void Ciphertext::save(ostream &stream) const`, 
I have no idea how to send the **ciphertext** (which is in `ostream`) by socket in client (of course also have no idea how to receive in server).

I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675358/how-to-send-ostream-via-boost-sockets-in-c), but it seems that it could not work when the data is **binary data**.

I would like to know how to write the code of sending `ostream` in client and receiving in server. Thank you.

Comment: You could write (or find) a custom `std::streambuf` class that wraps your socket, then you can assign that class to a standard `std::ostream`, thus allowing `save()` to output (in)directly to your socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it `ostringstream` to fill and the extact the string containing binary data from it:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
// ...
std::string save_into_string(Ciphertext const& ciphertext) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    ciphertext.save(s);
    return s.str();
}
```